# Aes encrypt MemoryStream.ToArray empty

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

I have a problem with `AesEncrypt`, I have this block of code that encrypts a text:

```
private byte[] EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(string plainText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
{
    // Check arguments. 
    if (plainText == null || plainText.Length <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
    if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
    if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
    byte[] encrypted;
    // Create an Aes object 
    // with the specified key and IV. 
    using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
    {
        aesAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
        aesAlg.Key = Key;
        aesAlg.IV = IV;

        // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
        ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

        // Create the streams used for encryption. 
        using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                {
                    swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                    csEncrypt.FlushFinalBlock();
                }
            }
            encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
        }
    }

    // Return the encrypted bytes from the memory stream. 
    return encrypted;
}
```

The problem is that in some cases, `msEncrypt.ToArray()` returns me an empty `byte[]`, and in some cases, it works well...

Save my day please!

Comment: i create a sample project... http://sdrv.ms/1626zBQ

Comment: why not simply `encrypted = encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(plaintext, 0, plaintext.Length)`? Streams are useful for incremental encryption, but if you have the whole message in a single array, there is no reason to jump through all those hoops.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to flush `swEncrypt` before calling `FlushFinalBlock()` to ensure that all the data you're trying to encrypt gets passed to the `CryptoStream`.

Change

```
swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
csEncrypt.FlushFinalBlock();
```

to

```
swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
swEncrypt.Flush();
csEncrypt.FlushFinalBlock();
```

After making this change the `CryptoStream` will now throw an exception if the input is not a multiple of block size, which is 16 bytes in the case of AES.

You have two options to fix this issue.

1. Pad your input manually up to a multiple of the block size. For `"This is a test string"`, you'd pad it to something like this `"This is a test string\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"`. The padding character can be whatever you want, just be sure to remove the padding after decryption.
2. Change the padding mode to something else like `PKCS7` or `Zeros`. Unless you absolutely need to use `PaddingMode.None` (for compatibility with some other system for example), this is the better solution.

Comment: i change the paddingmode to PKCS7, now encrypt the string, but i can't decrypt. i update the project with the sample. http://sdrv.ms/18WxWA1

Comment: nothing... also with the Flush(), return me the error "Padding is invalid and cannot be removed"

Comment: Update answer. The problem you're having with "padding is invalid" is due to this `Encoding.Unicode.GetString(encrypted)`. `encrypted` contains binary and trying to convert it to unicode is damaging the data. If you want to convert `encrypted` to a string, you need to encode it to Hex or Base64.